# error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in Eclipse

Tags: java

So, I've been trying to make my own custom icon pack, but when I try to clean the project, it appears there is an error:

```
Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token).
```

Here are the lines that are shown in the problems tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<version>1</version>
<iconmask imgl="iconmask01"
<scale factor="0.75" />
```

The error is in

Comment: `iconmask` start tag is not closed.

Comment: change `<iconmask imgl="iconmask01"` to `<iconmask imgl="iconmask01"/>`

Comment: Use https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ in case of doubts about sintax

Comment: still can't, the error was in <scale factor="0.75" />

Comment: @MiftachuzID Please update your question with your current XML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your "XML" is not well formed so is not technically xml. the element `<iconmask imgl="iconmask01"` is not closed, if you close it (`<iconmask imgl="iconmask01" />`) then you will have well formed XML and this problem will be fixed.

Additionally I notice your root element is not closed, did you only paste a fragment?

Comment: still can't, the error was in <scale factor="0.75" /> line

Comment: have you closed the element `iconmask`?

Comment: have you closed the root element?

Comment: yes I did, that's why i post this. still figure it out

Comment: where should i send you?

Comment: you can put the XML on here

Comment: it's too long to put here

Comment: Thanks guys for answering my question. I'm sorry for not uploading my complete XML cause my internet went down yesterday. But I just fixed my problem, by just retarting Android Studio. Maybe somekind of error or somthing.

Comment: No worries, if my answer was the one which solved your problem, is it possible for you to accept it?